# Where can I find a products feed/catalogue .xml from any online store with <g:google_product_category>?

Tags: data-request

is there any online store that can share its XML catalog/product feed? I need mainly product  and <g:google_product_category> ... I'll be using this data to research word embedding models for product category classification. Shopping-related corpus is really hard to find and I really need a storage dump for this research.